# Stop Visual Studio telling me 'nowrap' attribute is not valid

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, in my view (cshtml), sometimes I have some code not accepted. Here is a concrete example:

[image]

I know this is not a real problem. I wonder if I can "edit" the rules of VS to stop telling me there is a problem for this 'nowrap'. I don't want to desactivate all the warnings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get around this particular warning by using a CSS rule.

```
td {white-space:nowrap}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3rwWh/4/

Comment: I already try it but it don't works because the content of my td are not texts but buttons. SO any solution to make it work for buttons?

Comment: In fact the content of my td are: some <a> (anchor html tags) with a specific class in order to show them as buttons. I would like to be sure these buttons are showed on the same line and not wrapped. Thanks.

Comment: One way is to make some width calculations in your js/css that executes after the <a> tags have been transformed into buttons.  would you have a jsfiddle that would demonstrate how your page is working?